# Retrieve values from Scipy gaussian_kde

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

It's the first time I'm using Scipy because I couldn't find many libraries that could generate KDE data directly without plotting beforehand like what *Pandas* does (data.plot(kind='kde').
I'm trying to get the data in the KDE as a list or array but it's referring to the scipy object **<scipy.stats.kde.gaussian_kde object at 0x000002C4A8D077F0>**

Is there a np.array(density) *(Numpy)* or density.values *(Pandas)* similar function that could retrieve the values ?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats

data = [992.9832, 846.1371, 994.2491, ..., 0.0]

# generate histogram data
h, e = np.histogram(data, bins='auto')
width = 1 * (e[1] - e[0])
center = (e[:-1] + e[1:]) / 2
print(np.array(data).mean())
x = np.linspace(e.min(), e.max())

# plot the histogram
plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
plt.bar(center, h, align='center', width=width, label='histogram')
plt.axvline(np.array(data).mean(), color='k', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=1)
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# Plot KDE
density = stats.gaussian_kde(data)
print('DENSITY TYPE:', type(density))
print('DENSITY:', density)
plt.plot(center, density(center))
```

[image]

Comment: first check `print( dir(density) )` to see all properties and methods available in this `"gaussian_kde object"` - maybe it has method to get expected values. Maybe it has ie. `density.get_data()` or `density.x` or maybe it can get it as in dictionary `density["x"]`. You can also try `help(density)` to see documentation available inside code - `docstrings`.

Comment: or maybe you should simply get `center, density(center)` to have `X, Y` - like in `plt.plot(center, density(center))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One you have estimated the density

```
kde = stats.gaussian_kde(data)
```

you need to evaluate the density in the range of data (or a wider range, you can choose)

```
evaluated = kde.evaluate(np.linspace(data.min(), data.max(), 100))
```

Let's try

```
# generate random variates
np.random.seed(42)
data = sps.norm(loc=200, scale=5).rvs(100)
plt.hist(data, density=True);
```

[image]

now let's estimate and evaluate density

```
density = gaussian_kde(data)
data_space = np.linspace(data.min(), data.max())
evaluated = density.evaluate(data_space)
plt.hist(data, density=True)
plt.plot(data_space, evaluated);
```

[image]

and you have the array of the density in the range you've chosen (`data_space` in this case, but you can define the linspace you want)

```
print(evaluated)
[0.00371907 0.00455801 0.00561179 0.00693696 0.0085618  0.01047394
 0.01262245 0.01493411 0.01733577 0.01977291 0.02221777 0.02466837
 0.0271459  0.02969787 0.03240771 0.03540247 0.03884495 0.04290023
 0.04767829 0.05316985 0.05920179 0.06543718 0.07142939 0.07671788
 0.08093304 0.08387167 0.08551486 0.08598526 0.08546673 0.08412519
 0.0820653  0.07933652 0.07597516 0.07205101 0.06768935 0.06305743
 0.05832807 0.05364531 0.04911138 0.04479586 0.04075165 0.03701897
 0.03361161 0.03049646 0.02758628 0.02475911 0.02190045 0.01894903
 0.01592369 0.01291898]
```

### note

The evaluated PDF is not normalized, i.e. it doesn't sum to 1

```
evaluated.sum()
2.147314809573033
```

If you need to normalize it, you can simply divide it by the sum (equal to divide by the integral for a continuous variable)

```
evaluated /= evaluated.sum()
evaluated.sum()
1.0
```